# Error during pip install -Please check proxy URL

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have installed `anaconda` on my machine with python 3.7, pip version  19.0.3

I am trying pip install from Windows command line. I am getting the error for all package installations tried through pip. It would be great if some one can help me out.

Command given: `pip install lifetimes`

Eror message:

```
Collecting lifetimes
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Please check proxy URL. It is malformed and could be missing the host.
```

Comment: Are you looking for help with setting pip to use a proxy or are you having trouble with a proxy setup you already tried to configure?

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7969

Comment: Thanks for helping me.Tried the commands set http_proxy=http://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
set http_proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port and it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use pip behind a proxy, you can specify the proxy with the `--proxy` option.

```
pip install --proxy=https://user:pass@server:port packages
```

If you're going to do several pip installs in a given session, you can set your proxy variables in the terminal or command prompt. The lines below are taken from [here](http://leifengblog.net/blog/how-to-use-pip-behind-a-proxy/). If you have the ability to define the environmental varibles, do that once and you should be good to go.

```
# Windows
set http_proxy=http://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
set http_proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port

# Linux
export https_proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
```

At work, we still had some issues because some domains were not trusted, so you can add the following lines to tell pip that the following domains are okay.

```
--trusted-host pypi.python.org 
--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org 
--trusted-host pypi.org
```

If you want to set up Anaconda to use the proxy without having to specify the proxy each time, you need to create a `.condarc` file in your home directory. Add the following lines to the `.condarc` file and you should be good to go. More information can be found [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html).

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@server:port
    https: https://user:pass@server:port
```

Comment: Many Thanks for helping me  I have tried commands                                                   set http_proxy=http://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
set http_proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port and this worked perfectly fine.This issue was happening due to proxy.